# Bringing the previous expressions in LispWorks like in SLIME

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, slime, lispworks

I've just started using **LispWorks 7.1**

In **SLIME**, `ctrl` + up/down arrow brings the previous / next expressions.

How to do the same in LispWorks in the Listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Listener?

Depends on the keybindings. See <kbd>c-h b</kbd> for a list of bindings. See the editor commands `History Next` and `History Previous` in the list - there might be more than one keybinding for that. One can also customize that, if wanted. Use the function `editor:bind-key` for that.

Comment: Yep, that was in the listener. <kbd>c-h b</kbd> brought the key bindings in and <kbd>C-C  C-P</kbd> for the previous and <kbd>C-C  C-N</kbd> for the next were listed. Didn't know in LispWorks the Emacs style key bindings were used. Edit: Ops, the `<kbd>` tags were not formatted properly.

Comment: @Terry: also meta-p, meta-n, again like Emacs.

Comment: Yep, that does it, too.  If only I knew that those were like the Emacs. I 've noticed for instance that `C-x b`changes buffers. Pleasant surprise. I think I need to read the manual :)

Comment: @tfb note that this may depend on the LW preferences > Environment > Emulation > Editor keys are like Emacs ... (and similar). That's why I gave a version where one looks up the actual current keybindings.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: yes, you're right of course (and your answer was better than my comment).  I think I was assuming that if `C-C C-N` worked then there were emacs bindings in place, but that's not actually justified (also I'd mostly forgotten there were other bindings you could use with LW!)

Comment: @tfb: I too have emacs keybinds active. Btw., note that when one changes away from 'emacs bindings', it changes also the cursor (on my Mac).